# How to fix footer on top of content and can't scroll vertically on mobile view when use overflow x hidden?

Tags: php, html, css

So i try to make a page responsive, and i try to use overflow x hidden for mobile phone can't scroll horizontally. but the problem is when i'm on mobile the vertical scroll didn't work and footer is on top of content/back button.

code of footer:

```
<div style= "text-align: center;
                            height:65px; line-height:30px;
                            background-color: #7895B2;
                            position: fixed;
                            width: 100%;
                            bottom: 0;">
  <p style= "color: #F5EFE6;">Developed by Kelompok 2<br>
  Aldi, Raja, Yovan</p>
</div>
```

code css on the index:

```
<style>
      html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
body {
  position: relative
}
    </style>
```

Comment: Add `height:100%` on html and body. if not work,
try other approach: `display:flex` with `justify-content:space-between`. then use `flex-grow:1` to main element

Comment: do not work :")

Comment: share codepen link